# Shell extension doesn't work to open file

Tags: windows, windows-registry, shell-extensions

I created a new entry in the registry at

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell\Edit with Sublime Text 2\command

and the default key read

> C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe %1

Now when I right click on a file and try to edit a file using this shortcut, I am greeted with the standard "Open With" dialog box for windows. I understand that I could associate the file with Sublime Text, but I want to be able to open any file with this shortcut and have Sublime Text open it.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong with this registry key?

Comment: Did you reboot or log out and back in?   Windows doesn't reload the registry like you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You need to create another entry that will put the command into the context menu for files.  Something like this:
`[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\Edit with Sublime Text 2]

@="&Edit with Sublime Text 2"`

Answer (score 0):

If paths contain spaces, they must be escaped:

```
"C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" "%1"
```